# grunt.js task why not event listen?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

In order to operate the ssh on grunt plug-in, using the ssh2, I have created a task, but before the connect () later, on event occurs, the process will be terminated. What could be causing this?

there is no problem at the normal program you do not want to use the grunt.js. . .

Gruntfile

```
ssh2sample: {
        default_options: {
        options: {
        'host': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        'port': 22,
        'username': 'names',
        'privateKey':  'keys',
        'passphrase': 'pass'
    },
```

task/ssh2sample.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Please see the Grunt documentation for more information regarding task
// creation: http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks

grunt.registerMultiTask('ssh2sample', 'The best Grunt plugin ever.', function() {

// Merge task-specific and/or target-specific options with these defaults.

  var Connection = require('ssh2');


  var options = this.options();
  options.privateKey = require('fs').readFileSync(options.privateKey);

  var c = new Connection();

  c.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('Connection :: connect');
  });

  c.on('ready', function() {
      console.log('Connection :: ready');
      c.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
          //if (err) throw err;
          stream.on('data', function(data, extended) {
              console.log(extended === 'stderr' ? 'STDERR: ' : 'STDOUT: '+ data);
          });
          stream.on('end', function() {
              console.log('Stream :: EOF');
          });
          stream.on('close', function() {
              console.log('Stream :: close');
          });
          stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
              console.log('Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
              c.end();
          });
      });
  });
  c.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Connection :: error :: ' + err);
  });
  c.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Connection :: end');
  });
  c.on('close', function(had_error) {
      console.log('Connection :: close');
  });

  c.connect(options);
}
});
```

no problem ssh2connect

```
  var Connection = require('ssh2');


  var options = this.options();
  options.privateKey = require('fs').readFileSync(options.privateKey);

  var c = new Connection();

  c.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('Connection :: connect');
  });

  c.on('ready', function() {
      console.log('Connection :: ready');
      c.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
          //if (err) throw err;
          stream.on('data', function(data, extended) {
              console.log(extended === 'stderr' ? 'STDERR: ' : 'STDOUT: '+ data);
          });
          stream.on('end', function() {
              console.log('Stream :: EOF');
          });
          stream.on('close', function() {
              console.log('Stream :: close');
          });
          stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
              console.log('Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
              c.end();
          });
      });
  });
  c.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Connection :: error :: ' + err);
  });
  c.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Connection :: end');
  });
  c.on('close', function(had_error) {
      console.log('Connection :: close');
  });

  var key = require(fs).readdirSync(keys); 

  c.connect({
        'host': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        'port': 22,
        'username': 'names',
        'privateKey':  key,
        'passphrase': 'pass'
   });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Grunt tasks are synchronous. If your task is async (as your task is) you have to tell it to wait with `var done = this.async();` and then call `done();` when your task is done.

See: http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete